# What does options.inInputShareable mean?

Tags: android, android-bitmap, fresco

I'm implementing my own library loading and caching image. I follow `Fresco's` instructiona to decode image in `Ashmem` by using `options.inPurgeable = true` ( for Android 4.4 and below ).
I know that `options.inInputShareable` is used with `options.inPurgeable`. If I set `options.inInputShareable = true`, my java heap size almost doesn't increase. But I set `options.inInputShareable = false`, my java heap size increase obviously besides the `Ashmem`.

Could anyone tell me why? Thanks

```
"If inPurgeable is true, then this field determines whether the bitmap can share a reference to the input data (inputstream, array, etc.) or if it must make a deep copy."
```

Is the deep copy in Java heap? How can I set it in Ashmem?